# Why it repeats 5 times?

Tags: c++, string, while-loop

```
void firstSentence(void){
    string incorrectSentence;
    string correctSentence = "I have bought a new car";
    cout << "Your sentence is: I have buy a new car" << endl;
    cout << "Try to correct it: ";
    cin >> incorrectSentence;
    if(incorrectSentence == correctSentence){
        cout << "Goosh. Your great. You've done it perfectly.";
    }
    else{
        firstSentence();
    }
}
```

That's my function I am trying to call in my program. But I am stuck little and angry because I can't find solution on my own. What it does is, that if the condition in "if statement" is true, my output is not what I expected. Output is 5 times repeated "Try to correct it. Your sentence is: I have buy a new car ..

Why it repeats exactly 5 times and whatever, what's going on there and why it's not working?

Comment: What does the debugger tell you when you step through the code?

Comment: you do not need `(void)` in C++

Comment: What have you typed in?

Comment: Why are you using recursion (call `firstSentence()` if not correct)?  This should be a `for, while, or do-while` loop.

Comment: I did it with while loop, same output ..Tried it this way, didn't work again ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This:

```
cin >> incorrectSentence;
```

does not read a line but a whitespace-delimited token. If your input is the correct sentence, that means that the first time it will read `"I"`, while the rest of the sentence remains in the input stream. The program correctly determines that `"I"` is not the same as `"I have bought a new car"`, loops, and reads `"have"` the second time around. This is also not the same as the correct sentence, so it loops again and reads `"bought"`. This continues until everything is read from the stream, at which point `cin >> incorrectSentence;` blocks again .

The solution is to use

```
getline(cin, incorrectSentence);
```

...which reads a line.

Comment: not `cin.getline(incorrectSentence);`, `getline(cin, incorrectSentence);`. `std::getline` is a free function in the `<string>` header. `std::istream::getline` (as in `cin.getline`) works with raw buffers.